# How to do donut caching with c# mvc and Varnish?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, varnish, esi, donut-caching

I added to varnish config

```
sub vcl_fetch {

   set beresp.do_esi = true; 

}
```

}

In my mvc application I've a childaction

```
<div>@* this should not be cached, I change the returned value in my DB *@
        1 @Html.Action("GetHour", "Index", new { id = 5 })
    </div>

    <div>
        2
        <esi:include>@* this should be cached *@
            @Html.Action("GetHour", "Index", new { id = 5 })
        </esi:include>
    </div>
```

And added a Request header

```
Request.Headers.Add("X-Esi", "1");
```

But Varnish keeps caching entire page.

What do I miss?
I've notice in my browser the request header X-Esi doesn't exist.
Also Varnish remove properly the tag `<esi:include`

The code in action GetHour is pretty simple, just retrieve a decimal from SQL Server.

Comment: I do not think that you can place content inside an esi:include tag and expect this to be cached. You need to specify a src attribute on an esi:include tag: <esi:include src="/url" />

Comment: If you do not want a page to be cached you should specify a Cache-Control header with a max-age or an s-maxage of 0 to tell varnish not to cache

Comment: You're right. Change to <esi:include src="/Index/GetHour/5">
              </esi:include> and configure ttl to 0 and works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<esi:include>@* this should be cached *@
        @Html.Action("GetHour", "Index", new { id = 5 })
    </esi:include>
```

for this:

```
<esi:include src="/Index/GetHour/5">
          </esi:include>
```

And add to Varnish default.vcl:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
   set beresp.do_esi = true;

  if(bereq.url ~ "/Index/GetHour"){
    set beresp.ttl = 0s;
  }
}
```

This was partially answered by @ronald in comments above.
Had to remove the [ChildActionOnly] annotation also.